# ElasticSearch more_like_this not restricting to title filed

Tags: elasticsearch, morelikethis

The following code restricts all results to the "thread", "_id" which is great.

```
$data_string = '{
"from" : 0, "size" : 100,
"sort" : [
    { "date" : {"order" : "desc"} }
],
"query": {
        "match" : {
            "thread.title" : {
                "query" : "This is a test"
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

What I would like to do is use the more_like_this function instead of match. The following code works, but returns results from "post", "_id" as well as "thread", "_id".

```
$data_string = '{
"from" : 0, "size" : 100,
"sort" : [
    { "date" : {"order" : "desc"} }
],
"query": {
        "more_like_this" : {
            "thread.title" : {
                "like_text" : "This is a test",
                "min_word_len" : 2,
                "min_term_freq" : 1,
                "min_doc_freq" : 1
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

What do I need to do to restrict results to just "thread", "_id".

This is my mappings:

```
{
  "xenforo120" : {
    "post" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "date" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "discussion_id" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer" : "tweet_analyzer"
        },
        "node" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "thread" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "user" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        }
      }
    },
    "profile_post" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "discussion_id" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer" : "tweet_analyzer"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "user" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        }
      }
    },
    "page" : {
      "properties" : {
        "date" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "discussion_id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "node" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "user" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    },
    "thread" : {
      "_source" : {
        "enabled" : false
      },
      "properties" : {
        "date" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "discussion_id" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer" : "tweet_analyzer"
        },
        "node" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "thread" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "user" : {
          "type" : "long",
          "store" : "yes"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I needed to use "more_like_this_field" instead of "more_like_this"